# How to use python to draw pivot chart similar to excel pivot plot?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, pivot-chart

I want to create a pivot chart plot using python and below is the data format(csv file)

[image]

below is the pivot chart plot using excel:

[image]

The code I used to generate pivot chart:

expect to see the same result as excel plot[image]

As you can see from the figure created from python is not what I expected.
Any solutions for this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: post the data and not the pictures of data.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Name,Temp,Channel,Result,Setting1
A,25 ,1 ,-26.4 ,0.5
A,25 ,1 ,-28.6 ,0.6
A,25 ,1 ,-27.3 ,0.7
B,25 ,3 ,-26.7 ,0.4
B,25 ,3 ,-27.5 ,0.55
B,25 ,3 ,-28.5 ,0.8
C,25 ,5 ,-30.1 ,0.63
C,25 ,5 ,-29.4 ,0.77
C,25 ,5 ,-28.3 ,0.68

Comment: above is the data for Record1.csv